# How to make hydra brute force in one seclists file

Tags: linux, passwords, ftp, kali-linux, brute-force

I am trying to crack a ftp server with brute force. However, in seclists there are ftp file but its format is like:
`root:password`
I can brute force with multiple text files with command
`sudo hydra -t 4 -l (username list) -P (password list) -vV (ip address) ftp` but how can I brute force with single text file in format `username:password`? I want hydra to take the username and password in same file as in seclists. Here is the seclists ftp format:

```
anonymous:anonymous
root:rootpasswd
root:12hrs37
ftp:b1uRR3
admin:admin
localadmin:localadmin
admin:1234
apc:apc
admin:nas
Root:wago
Admin:wago
User:user
Guest:guest
```

like this.

Answer (score 0):

hydra -C userandpass.txt ftp://$vulnerableIP